# SSO and data API - should they be separate or unified?

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on

I'm working on a client project that involves creating three separate websites, with the goal of unifying them under SSO - so, one login gives you access to all three websites. All three websites will also be consuming an internal data API, so we're planning on a separate data server. Therefore, there will be a need for both detached authentication and data services.

My question is this - should data and authentication services come from the same API? Are there meaningful reasons to keep authentication and data as separate services? Or will separating authentication and data add complication without any return benefit? I'm leaning towards combining them into a single source, but with my limited experience in this area, I don't have complete knowledge of the risks involved (if any).

Over the past few days, I haven't been able to find relevant reading on this subject - all material I've found relating to SSO security concerns has more to do with 2FA and general security, or specifically OAuth authenticating intranets and more enterprise-level concepts (e.g. onedrive). Many articles are available relating to using SAML / OAuth to authenticate a data API, but none of them directly address whether an SSO service should be separate from or unified with the data service it protects. I see no closely related questions here either.

---

I'd like to explore this from a platform-agnostic, best-practices approach - but if context helps, the chosen platform for this is Laravel / Lumen.

Please also note, because the client is the only shareholder in this project, I have no ability to change the parameters of this project. E.g. We can't avoid building an SSO service ourselves - SSO with google / github is on the roadmap, but the client still wants to provide SSO if a 3rd party login isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

To provide Single Sign On to multiple web apps, you will need an Identity Provider (IdP). As you mention in your question you will want to use google / github in future but right now use first-party logins, you need to establish your own identity provider. Lots of FOSS software available - [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) comes to mind, which you'll need to self-host on a server. Alternatively, a very popular option with an option to use for free up to certain limits is [Auth0](https://auth0.com), which provides lots of SDKs, guides etc on getting up and running. Both of these identity providers will let you use a local database of users (first-party logins) and then later also allow users to sign in with third-party credentials (google, github, etc). Or, you can go the route of building your own identity provider service - but keep in mind that there are many intricacies which, if not properly considered / planned for, could lead to security issues later down the line.

Once you have somewhere you are storing your identities you will need to use a protocol - lots people use OpenID Connect & OAuth2.0 - that enables you to authenticate and authorise users against the identity provider to decide if they should have access (and to what degree they have access) to your web apps and your backend APIs.

So by the nature of what you are trying to achieve, you are likely to have your "SSO Service", or identity provider, separate from your data API. This is because they have entirely different concerns, and I would suggest also because you want to use your identity provider to control access to the data API, it likely wouldn't be part of the same codebase.

A good place to start reading further into the subject would be Auth0's [identity fundamentals](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/identity-fundamentals) pages. Auth0 also has a [Laravel SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel) which could save you some time.